# Simultaneous synchronisation of several QField files

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync

I would like to synchronise several QField files using one command in QGIS. Is this possible with a Python script?
I would like to use the plugin QField sync but for the data of 10 tablets. So that I don't have to synchronise each tablet individually, a script would be very time-saving. Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: I use rsync over wi-fi. On android side dropbear ssh server. Then it's just a matter of opening multiple terminals.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of this, but you can try using Mergin service (https://public.cloudmergin.com/) and Input app which is also based on QGIS.

To achieve that using https://inputapp.io and Mergin, you need:

- Upload your project to Mergin (using Mergin plugin in QGIS)
- All your users need to have their own accounts
- Share your projects on Mergin with your users
- Install https://inputapp.io
- Each user can access the same project from Input under Projects >
  Shared with me
- Download the project and make changes
- Sync the changes from Input, Projects > Home